# Infinite scrolling fills completely rather than incrementally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am attempting to create infinite scrolling on my web page using an example I found.  However, the page fills up completely with all the items instead of just showing several items at a time.  In other words it is not doing infinite scrolling.  I noticed in some of the examples they parsed out data in chunks but in the real world how are you supposed to do that?
Below is my html code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><tr>

            <th style="text-align:center;">User ID</th> <th>Username</th><th>Rank</th>
            <th>Posts</th><th>Likes</th> <th>Comments</th> <th>Flags</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>
            <tr><td class="center">
                     <div ng-app='scroll' ng-controller='Scroller'>  
                       <div  when-scrolled="loadMore("")">  
                        <div  ng-repeat='item in items'>
                    <span>{{item.id}} 
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:140px;">{{item.username}}</span> 
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:290px;">{{item.rank}}</span> 
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:360px;">{{item.posts}}</span> 
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:440px;">{{item.likes}}</span>  
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:530px;">{{item.comments}}</span> 
                    <span style="position:absolute;left:640px;">{{item.flags}}</span>
                    <span class="label label-success" style="position:absolute;left:710px;">Active</span>
                    <a style="position:absolute;left:790px;" class="btn btn-info" style="width:30px" ng-href='/admin/userDetail?userid={{item.id}}'> 
                                    View Detail</a>
                                        <hr> 

                    </div>  

              </div>
            </div>  
          </td></tr>
        </table>
```

Below is my angularjs code:

```
   function Scroller($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

   $scope.items = [];
   var lastuser = '999999';
 $scope.loadMore = function(type) {      

    todate = document.getElementById("charttype").value;
      var url = "/admin/getusers?type=" + todate + "&lastuser=" + lastuser;      
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http({
        'url': url,
        'method': 'GET'
    })
        .success(function (data) {

   var items = data.response;     
   for (var i = $scope.items.length; i < items.length; i++) {
         $scope.items.push(items[i]);
         count++;
         if (count > 100) 
         {
             lastuser = $scope.items[i].id;
             break;
         }  

   d.resolve($scope.items);       
    d.promise.then(function(data) {                            
     });         
 }   
 )
   .error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
 });         
return d.promise;       
}; 
   $scope.loadMore();
  }

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
 return function(scope, elm, attr) {
     var raw = elm[0];
     alert("scroll");
     elm.bind('scroll', function() {
         if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
             scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
         }
     });
 };
});
```

My question is why does my web page show all 3200 lines initially rather than allowing me to do infinite scrolling.  You will notice I put an alert in the scroll module and it is never displayed.  Do I have to incrementally read my database? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all of the items returned from your API call into `$scope.items`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     $scope.items.push(items[i]);
}
```

Don't you want to add only a subset of those items?

P.S. Might help if you create a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) to show the specific problem.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment about the directive not working, I put together [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7QnydAuHKQSoqJoiggyz), which is a copy of your code but with the $http get code ripped out. The "scroll" alert fires here. I think you're just missing a closing bracket on your for loop (since I don't have your API endpoint to test against, I can't actually run your code live).

**EDIT 2:**
I'm not sure why you aren't seeing the function fire correctly on scroll. I've set up [another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0MFWkaSyqgV27aNjlNH3) where I've changed the result of the scroll event firing to show an alert and load more items from a data variable, so you can see that the scroll event is firing correctly and it will load more items.

Comment: Yes,I think that is probably what I need to do but I couldn't find any examples on how to read subsets of data.  I did try using a counter, but the counter value was lost and only the first iteration of the loop was displayed.  I need to know how to read chunks incrementally in my logic as my data is coming back in a predefined order.

Comment: I updated the logic to read chunks of data 100 items at a time.  But whenScrolled is never called. That is the key question.  What precipitates a call to the directive whenScrolled?

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you're just missing a closing bracket on your for loop. In general though, setting up a Plunkr will help you focus on what the specific problem you're running into is, and will also help people answer your question quickly!

Comment: I will see if I can set it up on plinker as I will have to contrive a database since I can't use mine in plunker.  I have it now where it calls the whenScrolled directive on the first load but after that clicking on the scroll bar does nothing.

Comment: Updated with another plunker to show the Scroll event firing when you scroll the span the directive is applied on.

Comment: @Dave Any progress on resolving this? It seems like the basic foundation of what you're looking for is working, but let me know if not.